# What is int cost[N] in visual basic

Tags: c, arrays, vb.net, algorithm

I have the code below to translate to vb, I'm wondering what those bracket means. What's the difference between int `cost[N][N]` and `bool S[N]`

```
#define N 55             //max number of vertices in one part
#define INF 100000000    //just infinity

int cost[N][N];          //cost matrix
int n, max_match;        //n workers and n jobs 
int lx[N], ly[N];        //labels of X and Y parts
```

Comment: Damn. If I win this week's lottery jackpot, I'll have *inifinitely* many pennies!

Comment: Dim cost(N-1, N-1) As Integer

Comment: @us2012 It's true if you store it in half-precision float.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the difference between int cost[N][N] and bool S[N] ?

They are two different type of arrays.
`cost[N][N]` is two dimensional integer array of size `NxN` while `bool[N]` is one dimentional boolean array of size `N`.

visual basic conversion

```
int cost[N][N]; ==> Dim cost(N-1,N-1) As Integer
int s[N];       ==> Dim s(N-1) As Integer
```

See [VB tutorial](http://visualbasic.w3computing.com/vb2008/2/vb-arrays.php)

Comment: This question has two parts. You answered only one :)

Comment: What is the second question?

Comment: @SohaibI; **What is int cost[N] in visual basic?**

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is:

`cost[N][N]` is a two dimension array on the other hand `bool S[N]` is a one dimensional array. Now what are dimensional arrays you could read from here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure#One-dimensional_arrays

As to your second question

```
int cost[N][N];
```

is equivalent to:

```
Dim cost(N-1, N-1) As Integer
```

in VB